# Update SQlite ID

Tags: android, sqlite

What I need is to squentioal my ID after delete entry

So my Id start as that ( 1 . 2 .3 )

If I deleted row 2 .. it will be like that ( 1 . 3 ) and what I need is to be ( 1 .2 ) I know the ID is primary key so it can not be changed.

But I have 2 ideas but I don't know how to implement them

**First one** is to delete the Db and then create it again

**Second** is make new column *(Fake_ID)* and make it consecutive to can display it to the user but i do not know to make it

This is my code and if someone can edit it and write the queries to do that because I'm stil a beginner in android and sqlite, I will appreciate it

Thanks it advance

**MySQLiteHelper**

```
public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String TABLE_EMPLOYEES = "employees";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_EMPNAME = "empname";
public static final String COLUMN_AGE = "age";
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "empdb.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database creation sql statement
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
        + TABLE_EMPLOYEES + "(" + COLUMN_ID
        + " integer primary key  autoincrement  not null , " + COLUMN_EMPNAME
        + " text not null , " + COLUMN_AGE
        + " integer not null);";

public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log.w(MySQLiteHelper.class.getName(),
            "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_EMPLOYEES);
    onCreate(db);

}


}
```

**Employee**

```
public class Employee {

private long id;
private int age;
private String empName;


public long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public int getAge() {
    return age;
}
public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}
public String getEmpName() {
    return empName;
}
public void setEmpName(String empName) {
    this.empName = empName;
}
// Will be used by the ArrayAdapter in the ListView
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Name: "+empName+" Age: "+age+"   "+ "ID : "+id ;
}

}
```

**EmployeesDataSource**

```
public class EmployeesDataSource {


private SQLiteDatabase database;
private MySQLiteHelper dbHelper;
private String[] allColumns = { MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID,
        MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_EMPNAME, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_AGE , MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID};

public EmployeesDataSource(Context context) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    dbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(context);
}

public void open() throws SQLException {
    database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void close() {
    dbHelper.close();
}

public Employee createEmployee(String empname, int age ) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_EMPNAME, empname);
    values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_AGE, age);

long insertId = database.insert(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_EMPLOYEES, null,values);

    Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_EMPLOYEES,
            allColumns, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = " + insertId, null,
            null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    Employee newComment = cursorToEmployee(cursor);
    cursor.close();
    return newComment;

}


 public void deleteEmployee(long itemId){
     open();
     database.delete(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_EMPLOYEES, "_id = ?", new String[]{Long.toString(itemId)});
     close();
    } 







public ArrayList<Employee> getAllEmployees() {
    ArrayList<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();

    Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_EMPLOYEES,
            allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        Employee employee = cursorToEmployee(cursor);
        employees.add(employee);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    // Make sure to close the cursor
    cursor.close();
    return employees;
}

private Employee cursorToEmployee(Cursor cursor) {
    Employee employee = new Employee();
    employee.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
    employee.setEmpName(cursor.getString(1));
    employee.setAge(cursor.getInt(2));
    return employee;
}

}
```

**MeriUmarKeNaujawanoActivity**

```
public class MeriUmarKeNaujawanoActivity extends Activity {
private EmployeesDataSource datasource;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    datasource = new EmployeesDataSource(this);
    datasource.open();
    Button btnDone;
    btnDone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDone);
    btnDone.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Employee employee = null;
            EditText enterName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittxtEnterName);
            EditText enterAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittxtEnterAge);
            int age = Integer.parseInt(enterAge.getText().toString());
            employee = datasource.createEmployee(enterName.getText().toString(),age);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MeriUmarKeNaujawanoActivity.this, DisplayListActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

**DisplayListActivity**

```
public class DisplayListActivity extends ListActivity {

private EmployeesDataSource datasource;
ArrayList<Employee> values ;
ArrayAdapter<Employee> adapter;
SQLiteDatabase db ;
MySQLiteHelper helper;






 public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.displaylist);

        datasource = new EmployeesDataSource(this);
        datasource.open();
        ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
           values =  datasource.getAllEmployees();    
              adapter  = new ArrayAdapter<Employee>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
                    lv.setAdapter(adapter);



          lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int Position, long ID) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                 datasource.deleteEmployee(ID+1);

                 values.remove(Position);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();





                return true;
            }
        });


 } 

                }
```

Comment: Why do you need to update almost all id when one is deleted?

Comment: to   I can delete Item from listview and DB  at same time ( OnClickItemlisnter) it works with me fine with delete function for  first time 
but when i enter the app again the list view indext start from 0 again , and Db can't match with the new list view

Comment: I think that you have to change the approach and not trying to update the ID. There are other ways to achieve it without update the ID. could you post your code related with listview/ arrayadapter / cursoradapter? maybe the best way is refresh all listview after this deleting.

Comment: I shared it . have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update your listview after deleting any entry, just call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`. And all listview will update.

You really don't need to update the Id of entries in DB to achieve it. It is not a good design.

You are using ArrayAdapter, but the best approach for this case is user CursorAdapter.

Update your code for using CursorAdapter. Ex:

```
public Cursor getAllEmployees() {
    Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_EMPLOYEES,
            allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);

    if(cursor != null){
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }

    return cursor;
}
```

After, you have to use a SimpleCursorAdapter, that will be something like this:

```
    Cursor cursor =  datasource.getAllEmployees();    

    SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
                cursor, 
                columns, 
                to,
                0);
```

You have to define other variables. I recommend you read [this tutorial](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-cursoradapter-sqlite.html) to learn how to use Cursor adapter.

Comment: yes I did it in my code , but wat i need to update my Db again or make Fake_ID column to can match with listview because when i enter the app again it look like that  
listview Index (0,1,2,3)
Db index ( 1, 3 ,5 ,6 )

Comment: I cant find notifyDataSetChanged() in your code. Dont update yours Id for achieve it, You really dont need.

Comment: Please check the new code , and i can send for you the source code in ur e-mail

Comment: The problem is you are using ArrayAdapter.. But you have to use CursorAdapter in this case.

Comment: can you edit in the code please  to it works fine with me , i will appreciate it alot